# How to use a mapper in another mapper using Mapstruct and Kotlin?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, mapstruct

I would like to map an entity to a **DTO with a nested DTO** using **Mapstruct**, in **Kotlin**.

I have a first DTO defined as follow:

```
data class FirstDto (
    val something: String
)
```

This DTO is mapped in an entity and vice-versa using Mapstruct. Here is the Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface FirstMapper {

    fun entityToDto(entity: FirstEntity): FirstDto

    fun dtoToEntity(dto: FirstDto): FirstEntity
}
```

And a second DTO nesting the first DTO:

```
data class SecondDto (
    val somethingElse: String,
    val firstDto: FirstDto
)
```

As for the first DTO, I define a Mapper using Mapstruct. But, I would like this mapper to use **FirstMapper** to map the nested DTO. So I should be using the `uses` property of the **Mapper**.

**In Java**, this would look like this: `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = FirstMapper.class)`.

How should it be implemented using **Kotlin**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't differ much. Purely syntax differences.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = [FirstMapper::class])
interface SecondMapper {
   @Mapping(source = "firstEntity", target = "firstDto")
   fun entityToDto(entity: SecondEntity): SecondDto

   @Mapping(source = "firstDto", target = "firstEntity")
   fun dtoToEntity(dto: SecondDto): SecondEntity
}
```

Which generates

```
public class SecondMapperImpl implements SecondMapper {
    private final FirstMapper firstMapper = Mappers.getMapper(FirstMapper.class);

    @Override
    public SecondDto entityToDto(SecondEntity entity) {
        ...

        firstDto = firstMapper.entityToDto(entity.getFirstEntity());
        somethingElse = entity.getSomethingElse();
        SecondDto secondDto = new SecondDto(somethingElse, firstDto);
        return secondDto;
    }

    @Override
    public SecondEntity dtoToEntity(SecondDto dto) {
        ...

        firstEntity = firstMapper.dtoToEntity(dto.getFirstDto());
        somethingElse = dto.getSomethingElse();
        SecondEntity secondEntity = new SecondEntity(somethingElse, firstEntity);
        return secondEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the syntax and for this very detailed answer. Works like a charm!

Comment: @LppEdd I am doing something very similar but I am seeing a NPE when I run unit tests. e.g. Running unit to create/update the DTO, and it says firstMapper is null.